# RTC Python SSLv3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

I am investigating if we can use IBM RTC API to create workitem, get workitem, etc using python scripting. I came across python library "rtcclient" which can achieve the required tasks however I am unable to use it since I get error as "SSLV3 Handshake Error" during the rtcclient call. I receive the same error even with requests.get function as well

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='clm.demo.com', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: /jazz/authenticated/identity (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:726)'),))

I am able to retrieve the same details via cURL command however python still throws error. Below are my version details

IBM RTC CLM: 6.0.2
Python: 3.7.6
Libraries installed : cryptography, httplib2, pyopenssl, rtcclient, requests

Comment: Can you work out where the SSL connection is initiated? You'll need to configure it to use TLS 1.2+ only, probably the SSLContext.

Comment: There is already a great answer here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252991/ruby-restclient-to-access-rational-team-concert-rtc-rest/27970844#27970844). This answer clarifies everything but if you need more details here (https://jazz.net/library/article/75)